# Making webcrawler - Wont go into my for-loop

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

I'm making a webcrawler for fun. Basically what I want to do for example is to crawl this page

http://www.premierleague.com/content/premierleague/en-gb/matchday/results.html?paramClubId=ALL&paramComp_8=true&paramSeasonId=2010&view=.dateSeason

and first of all get all the home teams. Here is my code:

```
def urslit_spider(max_years):

year = 2010
while year <= max_years:
    url = 'http://www.premierleague.com/content/premierleague/en-gb/matchday/results.html?paramClubId=ALL&paramComp_8=true&paramSeasonId=' + str(year) + '&view=.dateSeason'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class' : 'clubs rHome'}):
        lid = link.string
        print(lid)
    year += 1
```

I've found out that the code wont enter the for loop. It gives me no error but it doesn't do anything. Tried to search for this but can't find what's wrong.

Comment: There are no links found in your `soup.findAll()` statement. Check the source and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided redirected me to the homepage. Tinkering with the URL I get to http://br.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/results.html

In this URL I get all the home teams name using

```
soup.findAll('td', {'class' : 'home'}):
```

How can I navigate to the link you provided? Maybe the HTML is different on that page

Edit: Looks like the content of this website is loaded from this URL: http://br.premierleague.com/pa-services/api/football/lang_en_gb/i18n/competition/fandr/api/gameweek/1.json

Tinkering with the url parameters, you can find lots of informations.
I still cant open the url you provided, it keeps redirecting me, but in the link I provided, I cant extract the table info from html (and BeautifulSoup) because it is gathering the info from that JSON above.

The best thing to do is using that json to get the information you need. My advice is to use json package from python.

If you are new to JSON, you can use this website to make the JSON more readable: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Sorry I'm a newb in this but doesn't this link:
http://www.premierleague.com/content/premierleague/en-gb/matchday/results.html?paramClubId=ALL&paramComp_8=true&paramSeasonId=2010&view=.dateSeason

Direct you to a page where the results from the whole season are? Then my idea is that you only have to change 2010 to 2011 in the url to get from 2011 and so on ..

When I use your URl I dont get the home teams either tho.

for link in soup.findAll('td', {'class' : 'home'}):
   print ('hae')
   lid = link.string
   print(lid)

Comment: Hey @Sjonni, check the edit I made, maybe it can help